# Does running Orbot mean I am running a Tor exit relay?

Tags: exit-relays, orbot

I downloaded Orbot on my tablet and I've been reading about the Tor network and I looked up "Is running Tor illegal in the U.S.". I found out about exit-relays and the Orbot app said something about exit relays when I set it up. Does just running Orbot mean I am running an exit relay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. By default, Orbot will not run a relay/exit/bridge. You may have seen one of the circuits Orbot built, which show the path your data will go through when using Tor.

Unless you have changed your settings to become a Tor relay, you should be okay.

Comment: And as far as legality goes, in the U.S. it's generally considered legal under safe harbor provisions to run an exit node.  See also http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/4534/7603 , http://tor.stackexchange.com/q/249/7603 .